# Weka Confusion Matrix

Tags: machine-learning, weka, data-mining, confusion-matrix

I have the following data set
weather.nominal.arff

```
@relation weather.symbolic

@attribute outlook {sunny, overcast, rainy}
@attribute temperature {hot, mild, cool}
@attribute humidity {high, normal}
@attribute windy {TRUE, FALSE}
@attribute play {yes, no}

@data
sunny,hot,high,FALSE,no
sunny,hot,high,TRUE,no
overcast,hot,high,FALSE,yes
rainy,mild,high,FALSE,yes
rainy,cool,normal,FALSE,yes 
rainy,cool,normal,TRUE,no  
overcast,cool,normal,TRUE,yes
sunny,mild,high,FALSE,no
sunny,cool,normal,FALSE,yes 
rainy,mild,normal,FALSE,yes
sunny,mild,normal,TRUE,yes
overcast,mild,high,TRUE,yes
overcast,hot,normal,FALSE,yes
rainy,mild,high,TRUE,no
```

I wrote a simple program as following.

```
   if (data.classIndex() == -1)
        data.setClassIndex(4);

    J48 classifier = new J48();
    Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(data);
    eval.crossValidateModel(classifier, data, 10, new Random(1));

    System.out.println(eval.toMatrixString());
```

I got the following result.

```
=== Confusion Matrix ===

 a b   <-- classified as
 0 5 | a = no
 0 9 | b = yes
```

Now when i use the same weather.nominal data set in Weka GUI, I get the following result.

```
=== Confusion Matrix ===

 a b   <-- classified as
 9 0 | a = yes
 5 0 | b = no
```

What changes I need to make in the program to get the result as generated by Weka GUI? Values are crossed in the resulting confusion matrices.

**Update**
I mentioned the arff file, but I am getting the same values from database, as I have stored the same values in database. The problem only appears when I use database, not when I use normal arff file.

Code to load the values from database.

```
        InstanceQuery query = new InstanceQuery();
        query.setUsername("postgres");
        query.setPassword("*****");
        query.setQuery("SELECT * from weather");

        Instances data = query.retrieveInstances();
```

[image: Image of the database table]

Comment: I've tried to recreate the confusion matrix your provided with your code, but was unsuccessful.  I used weather.nominal.arff, as supplied in the Weka installation directory.  I know it will make your question pretty long, but could you supply the training data? It is only 15 instances so it might not be too bad.

Comment: When using your file and your code I get a confusion matrix with 5, and 3 in the "a" column, then 4, and 2 in the "b" column.  I get the same result when using the GUI with J48 (default options) and 10 fold cross validation.  I'm probably not going to be much help since I can't recreate the error.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that I am loading values from database. I have saved the values in database from arff file as they are.. Only it creates trouble when I load from database, not when I use normall arff file. Sorry for misleading info at the start.